# Using Geonames API database update?

Tags: geonames

Last Thursday I created several places in Geonames (using the website UI). When I tried to retrieve these places using the API, I couldn't get them. In that moment I thought that perhaps the API database (is there something like that?) needed time in order to be updated with my new places.
Today I try to do the same thing and sometimes I get the correct response, and sometimes I get an empty response.

For example, I created the place `Comuna 1 Norte`, in Colombia. From the website I can see it. But from the API, sometimes I can retrieve it, and sometimes I can't.

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?name=Comuna%201%20Norte&country=CO&username=xxxx
```

What's going on?

Is there a problem with Geonames databases?

Do I have to wait more?

Comment: Try waiting a few more days, I suspect they have replication servers globally and it may depend on which one you are hitting.